# JScript Frame Get Loaded HTML

Tags: html, url, load, jscript

I'm creating a JScript frame and I need to get the loaded HTML code from it.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: I guess you meant with Ajax? Step 1. Include JQuery lib; Step 2. Call `$('#container').load('url.html')`; Step 3. Oh wait it's finished. Either that or copy and paste those endless pure JS functions.

Comment: Ok, I don't know who changed it, but it's JScript as in .NET NOT Javascript.

Comment: The code is for built in scripting in a desktop application.

Answer (score 0):

If the page loaded in a frame is on another domain (that you don't have any control over), then forget it; you can't.  If it's on the same domain - or the domain it's from is using [cross-origin resource sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) - then it's possible:

var frame = document.getElementById("container");
   var frameDoc = frame.contentDocument || frame.iFrame.contentWindow.document;

That will get you the document object for the frame; you can then call functions such as `getElementsByTagName` or `getElementById` on that object to return things from within the iframe.  If you just want all of the HTML, then you can retrieve that with `frameDoc.documentElement.innerHTML`.

(If the page is on another domain, but you do have control of that domain, then you'll need to set up cross-origin resource sharing on that domain to make this work - but even then, it won't work in all browsers.)

Comment: Unless you have some other reason for wanting the iframe, you're probably better off going without the iframe and just using AJAX.  The solution I describe above is best suited for making small modifications to an iframe that is visible to the user.